# Can I tell activerecord to not convert "datetime" data to objects when I access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

I have some code that simply accesses a datetime field so activerecord converts it to a Time object automatically when I read it:

```
@some_appointment.some_time
```

The problem is that sometimes the "some_time" datetime column has bad data.  "0209-12-20" instead of "2009-12-20".  This causes to Ruby to throw a "year too big to marshal" error just from accessing, and I can't seem to catch it as the error is not an exception.  Given that there is some invalid data in my database, I want to try and make the time object myself by reading the datetime string and using Time.parse so I can catch an exception if the time cannot be parsed.  How can I accomplish this?  Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you doing this to get rid of the one instance of bad data? If so it does seem like a lot of work, when you could either interface directly with the database to correct this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try `attribute_for_inspect`, as in:

```
SomeModel.find(:first).attribute_for_inspect 'some_time'
#=> ""2009-02-23 23:15:24""
```

You might also consider just writing a stand-alone script that doesn't use activerecord to go over your data in the database to normalize it or something. That would probably be faster than coding the special-case of bad data into your app.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this to see if it works, but have you tried `attributes_before_type_cast`?  It returns the data before Rails runs the type conversion, but I am not sure if Rails will try to do the conversion when it loads the objects anyways.

Example:

```
@some_appointment.attributes_before_type_cast['some_time']
```

Comment: or better yet: `@some_appointment.some_time_before_type_cast`

Answer (score 1):

You could override the default accessors like this in your model:

```
def some_time
  read_attribute(:some_time)
  rescue
    # Try to parse this guy
    self.some_time_before_type_cast
end
```